# Access HTTP Session in WebSocketHandler (Spring-websocket)

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, httpsession

Dears,
I'm trying to get an HTTPSession in my WebSocketHandler. I could do it successfully when I was using 'javax.websocket-api' but I'm now using 'Spring-Websocket'.

The config :

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfigurator implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        MyEndpoint endpoint = context.getBean(MyEndpoint.class);
        registry.addHandler(endpoint, "/signaling");
    }
}
```

When the connection is established :

```
    @Component
    public class MyEndpoint implements WebSocketHandler {

        private WebSocketSession wsSession;

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) throws Exception {
            this.wsSession = webSocketSession;
            // need to get the HTTP SESSION HERE        
            log.info("Opening: " + webSocketSession.getId());
        }
    }
```

And now this is an example of how I could do it using 'javax.websocket-api' :

The configuration :

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/signaling", //
        decoders = MessageDecoder.class, //
        encoders = MessageEncoder.class,
        configurator = MyEndpointConfigurator.class)
/***
 * define signaling endpoint         
 */
public class MyEndpoint extends NextRTCEndpoint {

}
```

Then I was Injecting the HTTPSession modifying the handshake :

```
public class MyEndpointConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config,
            HandshakeRequest request,
            HandshakeResponse response) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        config.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(), httpSession);
    }
}
```

And finally, it was accessible when the WS connection was established :

```
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
        this.wsSession = session;
        this.httpSession = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties().get(HttpSession.class.getName());
        log.info("Opening: " + session.getId());

        server.register(session, httpSession);
    }
```

I could not succeed to do something similar with 'Spring Websocket'. Any solution ? Please do not propose classes from StompJS as I'm not using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this one to use:

```
**
 * An interceptor to copy information from the HTTP session to the "handshake
 * attributes" map to made available via{@link WebSocketSession#getAttributes()}.
 *
 * <p>Copies a subset or all HTTP session attributes and/or the HTTP session id
 * under the key {@link #HTTP_SESSION_ID_ATTR_NAME}.
 *
 * @author Rossen Stoyanchev
 * @since 4.0
 */
public class HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {
```

And there is a sample in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-server-handshake) how to configure it:

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new MyHandler(), "/myHandler")
        .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
}
```

So, whatever you need from the HTTP session is going to be available in the `WebSocketSession.getAttributes()`.

Comment: great, I'll test later on today, thank you for the reply !